# Extent projection from UTM to latlon (WGS84) and back again to UTM

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, extents, clip

I'm trying to crop a raster *dtm.temp1* (with higher resolution and in WGS84) at the extent of another *dtm.temp* (coarse resolution in UTM). Using different approch I reach different results

I try following two different approach as follows:
1.

```
 > dtm.temp
    class       : RasterLayer 
    dimensions  : 668, 965, 644620  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution  : 64.9, 92.6  (x, y)
    extent      : 437230.1, 499858.6, 5138842, 5200699  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : +init=epsg:32632 +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
    data source : in memory
    names       : elev 
    values      : 362.8404, 3584.865  (min, max)
```

Using this extent I convert it in longlat in the following way

```
# I build a spatial dataframe with extent data from dtm.temp
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:2, X = c(dtm.temp@extent@xmin, dtm.temp@extent@xmax),
                           Y = c(dtm.temp@extent@ymin, dtm.temp@extent@ymax))
coordinates(df) <- c("X", "Y")
crs_text <- crs(dtm.temp, asText=TRUE) # extracting crs from dtm.temp 
proj4string(df) <- CRS(crs_text) 
ext.lonlat <- spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
ext.lonlat

> ext.lonlat
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 2 
extent      : 8.183449, 8.998142, 46.40024, 46.95982  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : ID 
min values  :  1 
max values  :  2
```

at this point I use the extent (expressed as longlat) to crop the following raster dtm.temp1 (always in longlat but with a different initial extent and higher resolution)

```
> dtm.temp1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 9956, 14656, 145915136  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 7.857917, 11.92903, 44.27042, 47.03597  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory 
names       : elev
values      : -18, 4543  (min, max)
```

then

```
dtm.temp1.crop <- crop(dtm.temp1, ext.lonlat)

> dtm.temp1.crop
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2015, 2933, 5909995  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777779, 0.0002777772  (x, y)
extent      : 8.183473, 8.998195, 46.40014, 46.95986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

and then I project again in UTM the raster cropped at the same extent (or at least, so I believed..)

```
 # crs_text as defined above 
  dtm.temp1.crop.proj <- projectRaster(dtm.temp1.crop, crs=crs_text)

>dtm.temp1.crop.proj
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2033, 2968, 6033944  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 21.2, 30.9  (x, y)
extent      : 437083.4, 500005, 5138362, 5201182  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:32632 +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : elev 
values      : 360, 3603.655  (min, max)
```

as you can see the two extent dtm.temp (the starting one) e the final dtm.temp1.crop.proj seems to be too much different.

```
extent dtm.temp           : 437230.1, 499858.6, 5138842, 5200699
extent dtm.temp1.crop.proj: 437083.4, 500005,   5138362, 5201182
```

The error (in meters) is:

```
> 437230.1 - 437083.4
[1] 146.7
> 499858.6-500005
[1] -146.4
> 5138842 - 5138362
[1] 480
> 5200699-5201182
[1] -483
```

2. Using a different approach (easier but computationally time consuming) I follow this steps:

   ```
       > dtm.temp.extent <- extent(dtm.temp) # is the extent fixed
       > dtm.temp.extent
       class       : Extent 
       xmin        : 437230.1 
       xmax        : 499858.6 
       ymin        : 5138842 
       ymax        : 5200699 
   # then I project directly the second raster dtm.temp1 using the crs 
   # with projectRaster (very slow)
       > dtm.temp1.proj <- projectRaster(dtm.temp1,crs=crs_text)
   # then I crop to the fixed extent
       > dtm.temp1.proj.crop <- crop(dtm.temp1.proj, dtm.temp.extent)
   # this is what I obtain        
       > extent(dtm.temp)
       class       : Extent 
       xmin        : 437230.1 
       xmax        : 499858.6 
       ymin        : 5138842 
       ymax        : 5200699 
       > extent(dtm.temp1.proj.crop)
       class       : Extent 
       xmin        : 437233.6 
       xmax        : 499852 
       ymin        : 5138857 
       ymax        : 5200688
   ```

   the error now appears to me very reasonable:

   ```
   > 437230.1 - 437233.6 
   [1] -3.5
   > 499858.6 - 499852
   [1] 6.6
   > 5138842 - 5138857 
   [1] -15
   > 5200699 - 5200688 
   [1] 11
   ```

The reason of the first approach is only because I'm trying to speedup the code (very time consuming in the second approach).

(Edited) I add, it may be useful for someone, an image of the problem (the two points of the extent - LL and UR - far from raster even if on a different raster respect to the one above in the question) and the solution of Mkennedy in comments that works fine (using four points).

[image: Raster projected in UTM]

Comment: When you warp the bounding box from one projection into another it also rotates. The corner coordinates of the source box are not at the corners of the envelope of that rotated box any more. It is wrong belief that the source envelope would round-trip back to original.

Comment: Also, if both rasters have different resolution, is too difficult to have the same extent (if you make a corners rectification)

Comment: @aldo I don't expect to have the same extent obviously

Comment: @user30184 I'm not an expert in spatial projection but I'm following the rule to trasform Spatial points dataframe from different crs in R. What is wrong there? I don't understand why the first approach reach results so different. Following your argument means spTransform doesn't work properly?

Comment: spTransform works correctly, but a bended raster has a different rectangle extent after reprojecting. It would help yourself if you visualize the rasters with ggplot or in a GIS software like QGIS.

Comment: @AndreJ in R a raster extent is defined by 2 points (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) . I can change the projection system (crs) but the points should remain the same in a different reference system. If it is like you say why the second approach drive to correct results?

Comment: For the first workflow, try unprojecting all four corners of the raster, LL, UL, UR, LR and then take the min/max of the 8 values. You're not catching the rotation that occurs when unprojecting to lat/lon if you only do the LL and UR coordinates. If you take the true min/max, your results should more closely match the 2nd workflow.

Comment: On a larger scale, you even get the edges bended, with a new extent coordinate in the middle of the corners (especially if the original edge was in parallel with the axes).

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you. I think that you focused the reason of first workflow discrepacy. Thank you for the time of you all.